# Error when switching form in visual studio [VB.NET - beginner]

Tags: vb.net, forms, encryption

For one of my class, I have to make a small encryption program. In my program, I have three form: frmMenu, frmEncodage, frmChiffrement. When the program launches, the Menu form pops up. After that, theres a ComboBox which lets you choose between two type of encryption. After you make your choice, you press a button to start. Sadly, when I finished coding one of the encryption form (frmEncodage), my program wouldn't let me open the form when I was selecting it in the menu. The error popped up:
"An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Conversion from string "a" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

I have no idea how to fix it and I need your help to help me. Heres the code in my frmMenu :

```
Private Sub btnDebuter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDebuter.Click
    If cbxMenuChoix.Text = "Rotation" Then
        Me.Hide()
        frmEncodage.Show()
    ElseIf cbxMenuChoix.Text = "Chiffrement par substitution" Then
        Me.Hide()
        FrmChiffrement.Show()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Veuillez entrer un choix d'encodage")
    End If
End Sub
```

And this is the code for frmEncodage:

```
Dim boEncodageNeg, boMajuscule As Boolean
Dim inDecalage As Integer
Dim inProfondeur As Integer
Dim tbValeurLettre() As Integer = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
Dim byValeurFinal As Byte
Dim stInput, stLettre, stChaine As String
Dim inLettreNum As Integer


Private Sub btnRotRetour_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRotRetour.Click
    Me.Hide()
    frmMenu.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub btnRotAide_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRotAide.Click
End Sub

Private Sub btnRot13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRot13.Click

End Sub
Private Sub btnRotChiffrer_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRotChiffrer.Click
    stInput = rtbRotInput.Text
    For i = 1 To stInput.Length - 1
        For ii = 0 To inProfondeur
            If ii = 0 Then
                stLettre = stInput.Chars(i)
            End If
            If stLettre = stLettre.ToUpper Then
                boMajuscule = True
            Else
                boMajuscule = False
            End If
            stLettre.ToLower()
            For iii = 0 To tbValeurLettre.Length - 1
                If stLettre = tbValeurLettre(iii) Then
                    inLettreNum = iii
                End If
            Next
            byValeurFinal = inDecalage + inLettreNum
            If byValeurFinal > 25 Then
                byValeurFinal = byValeurFinal - 25
            End If
            stLettre = tbValeurLettre(byValeurFinal)
        Next
        stChaine &= stLettre
    Next
    rtbRotOutput.Text = stChaine
End Sub
Private Sub btnRotDechiffrer_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRotDechiffrer.Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
Dim tbValeurLettre() As Integer = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
```

You tell the computer to create an array of `Integer`s, but fill it with `String`s (pieces of text enclosed in quotes). Write `"a"C`, `"b"C` etc to create [`Char`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sx7t66b.aspx) which *can* be converted to `Integer`s.